# Validate internet connection or Azure service - Xamarin

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

I have a application develop in Xamarin (Cross Platform) that now run great!! But always need internet connection. 
If internet connection will fail,  my app suffers an unexpected shutdown. I would like controle this. 
First I have "AzureDataService" class:

```
public class AzureDataService 
{ 
    //Conexion to backend  
    public MobileServiceClient MobileService { get; set; } 

    //Object of "Ficha" class.  
    IMobileServiceSyncTable<Ficha> tablaFicha; 

    public async Task Initialize() 
    {
        if (isInitialized) 
            return;
        MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("http://linkbdd");

        //Save data in a local DB, later upload with internet connection
        const string path = "bbddMuestra.db";

        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);//Create DB

        store.DefineTable<Ficha>();

        //async initialization
        await MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());

        //Inicializate table
        tablaFicha = MobileService.GetSyncTable<Ficha>();

        isInitialized = true;
    }

    //Here get data 
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Ficha>> GetData() 
    {
        await Initialize();
        await SyncFicha();
        //Select data...
        return await tablaFicha.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToEnumerableAsync();
    }   

    public async Task SyncFicha()
    {
        await tablaVehiculos.PullAsync("Ficha", tablaFicha.CreateQuery());
        await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
    }
```

End of "AzureDataService" class. Now the class when implement AzureDataService.

```
public partial class ListaFichas : ContentPage 
{ 
    public static ObservableCollection ficha;

    public ListaFichas () 
    { 
        InitializeComponent ();  
        ficha = new ObservableCollection(); 
    }  

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {   
        base.OnAppearing();
        ficha.Clear();      

        //Next line get data from previous method of class "AzureDataService"
        var ligas = await App.AzureService.GetData();
        foreach(var item in ligas)
        {
            Ficha fi = item;
            ficha.Add(fi);
        }   
        //Here bind listview with data that previous get
        lsvFichas.ItemsSource = ficha;
    }
```

Please help me. I would like show a Display or DisplayActionSheet to inform user...But never unexpected shutdown.
Thanks!...

Comment: UWP Community Toolkit has a HelperClass called `NetworkHelper` which has a method `NetworkHelper.Instance.ConnectionInformation.IsInternetAvailable`, If `yes` you have internet connection. You can use this and process to particular requirement.

Comment: There is a cross-platform plugin Connectivity developed by James. Besides you always can use try/catch to get timeout exception if you cannot connect. You should do it anyway as any connectivity flag can be wrong. I experienced many times getting connectivity true when it was not connected and visa versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check internet connection

Below link is useful for you

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/276931#Comment_276931

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if you call `PushAsync` to **PUSH** the sync content, then the list of creates, updates and Deletes against your offline tables would be sent one by one to the Azure App Service. Both `PullAsync` and `PushAsync` operations need your mobile client online.

Per my understanding, you could check the internet connection before call `SyncFicha` for sync your data. Also, you could just wrap your `SyncFicha` method with `try-catch` for both handling the internet connection and conflict when you pushing the offline data. I recommend that you could refer to the following tutorials from adrian hall's book as follows:

- [Detecting Connection State](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#detecting-connection-state)

  Use [Xam.Plugin.Connectivity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity/) for checking connectivity state as follows:

  ```
  await Initialize();

  if (!(await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable(Client.MobileAppUri.Host, 443)))
  {
      Debug.WriteLine($"Cannot connect to {Client.MobileAppUri} right now - offline");
      return;
  }

  await tablaVehiculos.PullAsync("Ficha", tablaFicha.CreateQuery());
  await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
  ```
- [Handling Conflict Resolution](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#handling-conflict-resolution)